# jQuery change form action doesn't work for some IE 7 users

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I'm having a puzzling issue with Javascript/jQuery and a handful of IE 7 users.  I'm lost since I can't reproduce the issue with any IE 7 installation.  Here's the code:

```
   $("form").submit(function() {
            $(this).attr("action",$(this).attr("action").replace(/^\/foo/,""));
            $("input[type=submit]", this).attr("value","Please wait...");
            $("input[type=submit]", this).attr("disabled","true");
            return true;
    });
```

This removes for /foo from the form action and submit's the form without issue in all modern browsers.  But for some reason with SOME IE 7 users it doesn't update the action and submits it to the original.

I thought it was an issue with loading jQuery from Google, but I've moved it locally and other jQuery code executes from this same file without an issue.

Comment: Have you tried putting IE8 on those IE7 users' machines and running the debugger in compatibility mode? That's generally how I solve IE7 nonsense.

Comment: It's not internal so I can't force them to upgrade. This would probably fix it though since I haven't heard of anyone with IE 8 having the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the regex case insensitive.  (`/^\/foo/i`)